# Should I create new PubSub instance for every task in each task of Google Cloud Tasks?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-tasks

I'm working on code that will pull from Google Cloud PubSub.  This code is run by Google Cloud Tasks using AppEngine.  I created a new subscription in the topic and all of the task instances will pull from this single subscription.  Since the task can sometime killed by Cloud Tasks, I'm hoping that I can replay entire events by replaying a snapshot that will be created when the failed task execution begin.  Each tasks will pull from the their own subscription in the topic.

What would be the recommended approach for this case:  should I use a single shared PubSub instance like `export myPubSub = new PubSub({projectId})` then have each tasks use the shared `myPubSub`, or should I create a new instance of PubSub for every task (including the failed task)?

Cloud Tasks will call an endpoint to start a new task, if I'm using the single shared PubSub instance approach, I believe the instance will be shared for all tasks in the same App Engine instance.  Would this have better performance compared to creating new PubSub instance for every new task?

Comment: When you say "create a new Pub/Sub instance," what do you mean? Create a new subscription? A new topic? When you say "the task can sometime killed by Cloud Tasks," what do you mean? Is your general architecture that a message sent via Cloud Tasks tells an AppEngine instance to start pulling messages from Google Cloud Pub/Sub and then subsequent messages may tell the task to shut down?

Comment: I mean something like `const pubsub = new PubSub({projectId});`.  I'm asking this question after reading https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/550, looks like sharing `new PubSub()` in public namespace vs always create new instances matters.  In my case, all tasks pull from the same subscription and share the same PubSub instance (per App Engine instance).  The replay just to be prudent in case the task forcibly terminated (unplanned).

Comment: Having all tasks pull from the same subscription and ack only the messages they want to process is going to be an inefficient way to get the right data to the right tasks. There is no guarantee that messages will even go to the right task. If you don't ack or nack the other messages, they won't be redelivered until the ack deadline passes.

You either want to use separate subscriptions where you immediately ack all of the messages you aren't interested in (in which case your question is relevant) or you want to have one subscriber who reads messages and distributes them to the right task.

Comment: Makes sense.  I've updated the question and changed the implementation. But, the question is still unanswered: should I create `new PubSub()`  locally in the controller for each task, or use a shared global variable for the `new PubSub()` instance?  Each task is an endpoint of Node Express app.

Comment: Do you still need help with this one? To achieve low latency publishing, cache the publisher client by initializing it as a global variable https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq